# SQL Query in PHP with unknown type

Tags: php, sql, types

I would like to store a value which is sometimes a string, sometimes an integer. (In PHP and mySQL)

The variables are set up like this:

```
$userID = 123; // Unique primary key, always a number
$name = "nameOfTheProperty"; // Always a string
$value = "someText" or 1234; // Depending on the property to save
```

This works if its a integer property:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO saves (`User_ID`, `$name`) VALUES ($userID, $value) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `$name`=$value";
```

And this if its a string property:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO saves (`User_ID`, `$name`) VALUES ($userID, '$value') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `$name`='$value'";
```

How can I get this to work in general? Best in one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL won't care if you pass in a 'string' to a numeric field:

```
INSERT INTO (intfield, charfield) VALUES ('42', '42')
```

would insert `42` into both fields.

However, what you're doing is basically vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should be using a prepared statement and placeholders. Unfortunately, placeholders cannot represent anything other than VALUES, so you'd still need to build part of your query dynamically, e.g.

```
$safefield = $db->real_escape_string('nameOfField');

$sql = "INSERT INTO yourtable (`$safefield`) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($value_for_field));
```

Comment: I already prefiltered the variables with urlencode(). Is that enough? And $name can only have one of some defined values.

Comment: no. urlencode is utterly useless for sql injection prevention.

Comment: Can you give me an example value that would be harmfull after urlencode?

Comment: sql injection isn't something you can just point at something and go "this is harmful". injection attacks depend on the structure of the query being injected. just becaue urlencode() will quote out SOME characters that can be used in injection attacks doesn't mean it'll cover ALL characters that can be misinterpreted. Don't use urlencode and think you're safe. That's exactly the WRONG attitude to have.

Answer (score 1):

A column can have only one type. So define the column as `varchar` and use quotes every time.

Better sollution is to use prepared statements.

Comment: I've got multiple columns, some of them string, some of them int. The column to write into is defined by the $name variable.

Comment: @Aron then use qouted string. the conversion will be done by the database. or use prepared statement.